# oracle times out even when query is executed

Tags: oracle, session-timeout

We are using oracle 12.1 at work.  We have issues with the oracle session timing out after the 15 minute mark even after executing sqls(select/update/insert/delete).  The sqls are not long running(usually executes in less than 10 seconds)It does not do this consistently and it does not seem to matter which tool we use(SQLplus, PL/SQL, Advanced Query Tool, Powerbuilder).

Please note that the timeout is set to 15 mins and we cannot change this due to federal regulations.  Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Timeouts can occur at multiple levels: tcp, oracle session, http, application, etc. You may need to trace to determine _where_ it is occuring.

Comment: Are you saying that the session takes more than 15 minutes to time out and you want it to die exactly at 15 minutes? Or are you saying that the session times out after 15 minutes but you don't want it to?

Comment: Hi Bob,  the session times out after 15 minutes but I don't want it to.

Comment: How exactly is the timeout implemented?  With an Oracle profile with IDLE_TIME set to 900 (15 minutes)?  Or at a network level that drops all connections after 15 minutes?  I work on a federal government contract and we also have a 15 minute timeout rule, but only for *idle* sessions.  Can you also add the exact Oracle error code?

Comment: Oracle timeout is set to 15 minutes.

Comment: @WestonGoodwin We'll need more details to debug this.  Is it a profile, resource manager, SQLNet setting, network rule, etc.

Comment: @JonHeller  Hi Jon,  Unfortunately I am unable to get specifics on this.  I have asked but have not gotten a direct answer so this question will have to be closed, but I am not sure how to do that.  Thanks for your willingness to help.

Comment: @JonHeller  Hi Jon,  They actually gave me more details.  What is going on is that the idle property on the user profile is set to 15 mins.  When we login to oracle using a tool, oracle shows my user id as having multiple sessions open.  And when I execute a query I have no control over "which" session gets used.  Which is why this problem appears to happen on an inconsistent basis.

Comment: @WestonGoodwin In that case the behavior will depend on the tool used.  If you're using PL/SQL Developer you're in luck, there's an option in Tools-->Preferences-->Connection-->Check connection that will ping the database every minute to keep the connections alive.  SQL*Plus does not have a similar feature.  I'm not sure about the other programs.

Comment: @JonHeller,  Hi Jon,  That does not work either.  Just pinging oracle doesn't seem to work because oracle creates multiple session when ever I execute a query against the database.  Is there a way to update the seconds_in_wait on v$session for a particular user?

Comment: @JonHeller,  I am aware that it is a view I just wonder if there isn't some function or syntax that would allow me to keep a session alive.

Comment: @WestonGoodwin If "Check connection" doesn't work then I'm not sure what will.  I'm surprised it doesn't work, I've used that feature in exactly this scenario many times.  Maybe there's some specific problem with your PL/SQL Developer version and configuration.  This might be a question for the company that makes it, Allround Automations.  I'd recommend posting to their forum or emailing their support.  Include the version, the exact ORA- error message and behavior.  They have ways to collect and analyze all client configurations, and are usually very helpful.